# Middleware next() routeHandler

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware

I am currently reading this article

- http://qnimate.com/express-js-middleware-tutorial/#prettyPhoto

At the section *Middleware* the author is explaining very well what the benefit of *next()* is.

Writing this

```
var app = require("express")();

function checkLogin()
{
    return false;
}

function logRequest()
{
    console.log("New request");
}

app.get("/dashboard", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){

    logRequest();

    if(checkLogin())
    {
        httpResponse.send("This is the dashboard page");
    }
    else
    {
        httpResponse.send("You are not logged in!!!");
    }
});

app.get("/profile", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){

    logRequest();

    if(checkLogin())
    {
        httpResponse.send("This is the dashboard page");
    }
    else
    {
        httpResponse.send("You are not logged in!!!");
    }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

By using *next()* can be much cleaner

```
var app = require("express")();

function checkLogin()
{
    return false;
}

function logRequest()
{
    console.log("New request");
}

app.get("/*", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){
    logRequest();
    next();
})

app.get("/*", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){

    if(checkLogin())
    {
        next();
    }
    else
    {
        httpResponse.send("You are not logged in!!!");
    }
})

app.get("/dashboard", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){

        httpResponse.send("This is the dashboard page");

});

app.get("/profile", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){

        httpResponse.send("This is the dashboard page");

});

app.listen(8080);
```

But what I don't understand is: How does *next()*  know if it should go as next in the */dashboard* or in the */profile* route handler ?

Comment: Depends on the request path. `next()` make the request go from one middleware to the next one in the pipeline. Whether the next middleware executes or not, it depends on the request path.

Comment: @Yousaf, ah okay I understand thats why app.get("/*",)
And then it will go to profile when path is profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to the next route in the "router handle list". The order is very important, in your example, the router list will look like
`GET /* (any thing)` -> `GET /* (any thing)` -> `GET /dashboard` -> `GET /profile`.

Your request from the browser is `GET /profile`, check the method and path by order:

is match anything -> Yes, do something, next

is match anything -> Yes, do something, next

is match GET /dashboard -> No, not execute dashboard handler, check next router in the array.

is match GET /profile -> Yes, do something, call `httpResponse.send` -> finished.

If you register a route before `app.get("/*",` route to check `login`, it will pass without check login

```
...
app.get("/secret", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){

        httpResponse.send("Tada!!!");
});

app.get("/*", function(httpRequest, httpResponse, next){

    if(checkLogin())
    {
        next();
    }
    else
    {
        httpResponse.send("You are not logged in!!!");
    }
})
...
```